# Rotation in differnet basis (change of basis)

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $\mathcal B $=
$\left\{\left[
\begin{matrix} 
2\\
3\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix} 
3\\
1\\
\end{matrix}
\right] \right\}$
 be the basis
And i have a rotation 
Matrix  $\mathsf A$ rotate 60 degree:
$\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    \cfrac{1}{2} & \cfrac{{\sqrt 3}}{2} \\
    -\cfrac{{\sqrt 3}}{2} & \cfrac{1}{2} \\
        \end{matrix}
\right]
$

Vector $\vec x = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
21\\ 
14\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$
since $\hat A=BDB^{-1}$
A hat is a transformation matrix for above basis (rotate 60 degree)
Question 1: 
How to find A hat? is it just use $\mathsf A$ as $\mathsf D$ and calculate with formula $\hat A=BDB^{-1}$?
Question 2: 
If u don't know the transformation Matrix both D and $\hat A$ only given Basis ,one vector and one image(the result of a vector under transformation it is $\hat A$$\vec x$ in this case )is it possible to find  D and $\hat A$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE: The third question is no appropriate for this forum.

Comment: OK it has been fixed

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have tried so far ? There is no real point in giving you the solutions to what appears to be a course problem, the goal is for you to understand.

Comment: In question 1 I am not sure about what is D is it just a transformation matrix like rotation 60 degree, reflection, .... what ever the basis like
just use [-1,0]^T [0,1]^T for reflection and however [-1,0]^T [0,1]^T is only for basis e1 e2 
if u want to rotate 60 degree in differnent basis just like above it is just simply use the above equation?

Comment: In question 2 I wonder how map 2.5 tiles on PC game works like AOC Red alert 2....? I tried to make a polygon shape map on the game tiles 
like 6 sided polygon it is easy on a graph paper since it has a standard basis 
If u want to copy your work form your graph paper to game u need to know what is the transformation